# Assign one project to multiple users in SugarCRM

Tags: project, sugarcrm, assign, multiple-users

**What I want**:- I need one project assigned to multiple users and have that project only visible to assigned users.

**What I have done**:-  I have created a module with the help of module builder with name `allproject`. If I use 'assigned to' field in `allproject` then it assigns to only one user and that project is only visible to the assigned user with the help of role - but it does not fulfill my requirement for multiple users to be assigned to the project.

**Also**:- I have created a many-to-many relationship in `allproject`, that created a subpanel of users in `allproject`, and assigned that project to multiple users but in user profile the project is not visible that was assigned to them in subpanel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a brilliant module SecuritySuite http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/securitysuite/ that can solve your problem completely: you'll assign users needed to a group and then assign project record to the same group. You also need to make some module settings adjustments (read manual supplied attentively). Thus you can restrict access only users "assigned" (i.e. included in the security group) to the project. Play with that module a little, it's really worth it to solve difficult SugarCRM' access restriction needs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Now I am going to do What you have said. thanks.